# ¿Por qué en cada iteración el valor de la variable "i" siempre vale el último valor posible?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, pdf

¿Cómo puedo generar 20 txt relativos a las paginas de un pdf ?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdfUtil = require('pdf-to-text');
var pdf_path = "/home/kevin/Downloads/principito.pdf";

        var i=0;
        for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
        var option = {from:i, to:i};

var doc='./file'+i+'.txt';
//Omit option to extract all text from the pdf file 
pdfUtil.pdfToText(pdf_path,option, function(err, data) {
     fs.writeFile(doc, data, function(err) {
        if( err ){
            console.log( err );
        }
        else{
            console.log(doc);
        }
    });

});
```

este es mi código , pero me genera lo siguiente:

```
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
./file20.txt
```

todo se concatena, supongo que es por el comportamiento asincrónico de nodejs , una manito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás generando una nueva función dentro de tu ciclo cada que llamas a la función `pdfToText`.

Cada una de esas funciones hacen referencia a la misma variable `i`, como el código no se ejecuta inmediatamente para el momento en que se requiere calcular el valor de la variable `doc` el ciclo `for` ya terminó su ejecución y el valor de `i` es 20

```
var doc='./file'+ i +'.txt';  // i = 20
```

El resultado es que todas las funciones escriben en el mismo archivo.

Este es un clásico problema en JavaScript que puede ser solucionado con una `IIFE`:

```
// Encerrar el código con una función
(function (doc) {
    pdfUtil.pdfToText(pdf_path,option, function(err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(doc, data, function(err) {
            if( err ){
                console.log( err );
            }
            else {
                console.log(doc);
            }
        });
    });
})(doc);
```

Una IIFE es una función que se declara y se invoca inmediatamente, le pasamos como parámetro la variable `doc` para que se genere una copia, de esta forma cada función va a tener el valor correct del contador `i`.

A este concepto también se le conoce como *closure*.

En ES6 el problema se resuelve más fácilmente usando la [palabra reservada](http://www.enrique7mc.com/2016/01/declaracion-de-variables-con-let/) `let` para declarar la variable `doc`. `let` permite declarar variables cuyo alcance es el mismo bloque donde fueron declaradas.

Comment: hola he resuelto el problema usando eventos(sockets) , para emitir y escuchar, es recomendable este tipo de solucion? , porque veo queme llenaré de sockets si la cosa crece

Comment: Probablemente no sea buena idea crear sockets para un caso como este, la solución que me parece mejor es usar `let` en Node, prueba para ver si te funciona.

Comment: me funciono con eso gracias.

Comment: Si te ha sido de utilidad puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta.